# How to query the most recent record in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to query the most recent status of a a document, but not having any success.  The tables I am using for my query are `docs`, `docStats` and `statusList`.

`docs` table:

```
| docId |  docTitle  | venIdFk |
+-------+------------+---------+
|     1 | Contract 1 |      81 |
|     2 | Contract 2 |      37 |
+-------+------------+---------+
```

`docStats` table:

```
| docStatIdPk | docStat |        docStatDt        | docIdFk |
+-------------+---------+-------------------------+---------+
|           7 |       1 | 2016-09-16 09:00:00.000 |       1 |
|          10 |       2 | 2016-09-16 09:30:00.000 |       1 |
|          11 |       4 | 2016-09-17 08:30:00.000 |       1 |
|          12 |       1 | 2016-09-17 10:00:00.000 |       2 |
+-------------+---------+-------------------------+---------+
```

`statusList` table:

```
| statId |     stat     |
+--------+--------------+
|      1 | Needs Review |
|      2 | In Review    |
|      3 | Denied       |
|      4 | Accepted     |
+--------+--------------+
```

Using the following I can get the most recent status of the documents in the docs table:

```
SELECT 
    d2.docId, MAX(ds2.docStatDt) AS maxStatDt
FROM
    docs d2
INNER JOIN 
    docStats ds2 ON d2.docId = ds2.docIdFk
GROUP BY 
    d2.docId
```

The result is correct:

```
| docId |        maxStatDt        |
+-------+-------------------------+
|     1 | 2016-09-17 08:30:00.000 |
|     2 | 2016-09-17 10:00:00.000 |
+-------+-------------------------+
```

But I need to add additional columns to the query, and this is where it breaks.  It adds all of the records for docId 1 because 'stat' is included in the SELECT, and there are multiple statuses for docId 1.  How can I write this query so that it only returns the most recent status of docId 1?

Here is the query as I have it now:

```
SELECT 
    d.docid, d.doctitle, d.doctype, d.docorg, d.docdept, 
    s.stat, 
    mdt.maxdate AS crntDocStatDtSet 
FROM
    docs d 
INNER JOIN 
    docstats ds ON d.docid = ds.docidfk 
INNER JOIN 
    statuslist s ON ds.docstat = s.statid 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         d2.docid, Max(ds2.docstatdt) AS MaxDate 
     FROM   
         docs d2 
     INNER JOIN 
         docstats ds2 ON d2.docid = ds2.docidfk 
     GROUP BY 
         d2.docid) mdt ON d.docid = mdt.docid 
WHERE  
    d.docid = '1' 
GROUP BY 
    d.docid, d.doctitle, d.doctype, d.docorg, d.docdept, 
    s.stat, mdt.maxdate
```

Here are the results:

```
| docId |  docTitle  | docType | docOrg | docDept |     stat     |    crntDocStatDtSet     |
+-------+------------+---------+--------+---------+--------------+-------------------------+
|     1 | Contract 1 |       3 |      3 |       2 | Accepted     | 2016-09-17 08:30:00.000 |
|     1 | Contract 1 |       3 |      3 |       2 | In Review    | 2016-09-17 08:30:00.000 |
|     1 | Contract 1 |       3 |      3 |       2 | Needs Review | 2016-09-17 08:30:00.000 |
+-------+------------+---------+--------+---------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       d.docId, 
       d.docTitle, 
       d.doctype, 
       d.docOrg, 
       d.docDept, 
       s.stat,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.docId ORDER BY ds.docStatDt DESC) as RowNumber
    FROM
       docs d
       INNER JOIN docStats ds
       ON d.docId = ds.docIdFk
       INNER JOIN statusList s
       ON ds.docStat = s.statId
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNumber = 1
```

It would be better to use a partitioned ROW_NUMBER().  MAX() the way you are using it could end up with more than 1 result.  If more than 1 would be desired if they are equal then simply use DENSE_RANK() in place of where ROW_NUMBER() is.

The route you are going is also a valid method but your ON condition for your join did not have ON ds.docStatDt = mdt.MaxDate which meant you were not actually limiting your results to the last record. Adding that condition in would probably give you what you want as well.

```
 SELECT
    d.docId, 
    d.docTitle, 
    d.doctype, 
    d.docOrg, 
    d.docDept, 
    s.stat,
    mdt.MaxDate AS crntDocStatDtSet
FROM
    docs d
    INNER JOIN docStats ds
    on d.docId = ds.docIdFk
    INNER JOIN statusList s
    ON ds.docStat = s.statId
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT d2.docId, MAX(ds2.docStatDt) as MaxDate
       FROM docs d2
       INNER JOIN docStats ds2
       ON d2.docId = ds2.docIdFk
       GROUP BY d2.docId
    ) mdt
    ON d.docId = mdt.docId

    AND ds.docStatDt = mdt.MaxDate

WHERE d.docId = '1'
GROUP BY
    d.docId, 
    d.docTitle, 
    d.doctype, 
    d.docOrg, 
    d.docDept, 
    s.stat, 
    mdt.MaxDate
```

Comment: Good answer but check your docs table alias with your column selected

Comment: @scsimon thanks I corrected what I get for copying pasting :)

Answer (score 1):

One method that can be quite efficient is to use `outer apply`:

```
select d.*, ds.*
from docs d outer apply
     (select top 1 ds.*
      from docstats ds
      where ds.docIdFk = d.docId
      order by docStatDt desc
     ) ds;
```

You can, of course, join in the status string as well, but that doesn't seem to be the gist of your question.